# Storing Data in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm creating an medication reminder application , i'm planning to keep all data in a list of array, will it be possible for me to store this list of array into the storage? If , it would be nice if you could show me how. Thank you!

Comment: You can find a working example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919306/storing-arraylist-in-isolatedstorage

Answer (score 2):

I've read a few of your posts here and I think you should take a look at [some background reading](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Open-Source-Databases-and-Helper-Libraries) to help.  If you map out your architecture then these samples will aid in the long-run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Please check this link to see [samples](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage)

It is pretty much like working with IO and file system.