# Storing arraylist in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

how do i store a list of array into isolated storage? Possible to place image inside the arraylist too? Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with isolated storage. This is about serialization in general.

Comment: So i'm able to keep my arraylist just like this? :O

Comment: like @usr said, you need to make sure that your arraylist is serializable and then you can store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments said all you need is to get some serializable object and you're able to store it in IS. Be awate that arrays of more than one dimension are not serializable!

Here is a code chunk I use for IS:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
public class IsolatedStorage
{
    public static void SaveToIs(String fileName, Object saved)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isf.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    isf.DeleteFile(fileName);
                }


                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = isf.CreateFile(fileName))
                {

                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(saved.GetType());
                    ser.Serialize(fs, saved);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    public static Object loadFromIS(String fileName, Type t)
    {
        Object result = null;
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isf.FileExists(fileName))
                {

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isf.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(t);
                        result = ser.Deserialize(sr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```